# unable to boot ubuntu 16.04 after using win 7

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a problem trying to boot Ubuntu 16.04.
I have 2 hard disk drives. One contains Windows 7 and the other contains Ubuntu 16.04.
I had to swap to the win drive to use a piece of hardware I purchased, I unplugged the Ubuntu drive and plug in the win drive. All OK so far, I then went back and used the Ubuntu drive, all 'seems' OK boots, runs programs, then suddenly stopped working completely. Reboot and go into bios settings, the hard drive does not show. I only have the option of using the CD drive and use Ubuntu without installing, this is to prevent the loss of all my programs and data.  Without the CD in the drive, the fault is "no media, insert media drive and press a key."
Did anyone face this situation?
If you know how to fix this I would like to hear from you please.
Regards,  Rod

Comment: I don't know your issue, but if was me, I'd boot your Ubuntu install/live media, and view your SMART data on the iffy drive. The `smartctl` (or gnome-disks or whichever tool you use to view SMART data from the drive) will show you the health of your drive from data stored on it's chips. I would rule out a failing drive before I explore the next possible cause...  (if the case is easily opened; I'd also consider a cap-check or quick scan of your motherboard, check the voltage of your CMOS battery in case it's close to dead (3V or less) and thus causing you issues)

Comment: Thank you for your input singrium, I looked carefully at all the electro caps, none appeared to be stressed.  I also tested the CMOS battery, this gave me an "AHA" moment, it was 2.92V.  Quickly removed the battery and purchased a new CR2032 hoping this might be the answer.  Sorry, still the same problem.  This however has saved another failure in the near future.  The system voltages all show correctly within .03 volts worst case.  Hope there are others with more info on this problem.  Regards,  Rod